# What happened to Ezio after revelations?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

What happened to Ezio after the events of Assassin's Creed Revelations?

Comment: This sounds like a "Why did the devs design it that way?" type of question.

Comment: It's a lore question, not a "Why did the devs design it that way?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> As showed in Assassin's Creed: Embers, Ezio retired from the Assassin Order and settled down in a Tuscan villa of Monteriggioni with Sofia and had two children, Flavia and Marcello. Years later, a mysterious Chinese woman appeared at his door requesting his help. The woman, Shao Jun, was a member of the Chinese Assassin Order and sought Ezio's advice in how to help her people and rebuild their order. After helping Jun fight off soldiers sent by the Chinese Emperor, Shao Jun leaves, armed with the wisdom she came seeking Ezio for.
>
> Shortly thereafter, while on a trip to the market square in Florence,
>   Ezio died of a heart attack. His legacy and contributions to the
>   Assassin order would continue to resonate for hundreds of years
>   following his death.

[Wikipedia: Ezio Auditore da Firenze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezio_Auditore_da_Firenze#Later_life)

See also: [Assassin's Creed Wiki: Ezio Auditore da Firenze](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Ezio_Auditore_da_Firenze#Later_life) (Too much info to directly quote all)

Answer (score 2):

The animated movie [Assassin's Creed: Embers](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin's_Creed:_Embers) is an animated short film project designed to expand the Assassin's Creed series. Set after Revelations, the film concludes the life of Ezio Auditore da Firenze, who retired from his life as an Assassin and lived with his wife Sofia Sartor in Tuscany's countryside.

You can see the [full movie on vimeo.com](http://vimeo.com/33192430), or through googling.

Answer (score 2):

Ezio retires from assassinating people and hunting for artifacts and so forth during the ending of Revelation:

In his own words "No, [...] I have seen enough for one life."

The Animus is used to send Desmond into the memories of former assassins who have critical information vital to the survival of the assassin order.  After the events of AC2, Brotherhood, and Revelations, Ezio says that his part in this has been concluded.

Answer (score 0):

If you had actually being paying attention to the story at the end of revelations, you would find out that

> he actually died like Altair did.

Which is the reason you don't play him in AC3.

Comment: Everyone dies, like Altair did.